# Degrees of freedom - binary vector

Tags: self-study, distributions, binomial-distribution

I came across the following statement:

> *A general distribution over a binary vector (of lenght $N$) has $(2^{N}-1)$ degrees of freedom, whereas a factorial distribution over a binary vector has only $N$ degrees of freedom*.

I am interpreting / understand this that a factorial binary distribution has one parameter (e. g. a binomial probability $\theta$) for each element of the vector. I understand that in a general distribution the elements of the vector might be correlated - but I am failing to connect this - see the intuition why the general distribution over a binary vector (of length N) has $(2^{N}-1)$ degrees of freedom. Any help welcome.

Comment: How many possible values of a binary $N$-vector are there?  ($2^N$.)  How many linear relations are imposed by the requirement to be a probability distribution?  ($1$.)  Maybe the statement you are reading therefore asserted the remaining DF are $2^N - 1$ rather than $2^{N-1}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment - and i will update the question. What i don't understand, and maybe i misinterpret the factorial distribution, is that the latter also can take 2^N possible values - no? I.e. if i have a vector of length 3 with independence between the distribution that creates each entry of the vector - then i would still have 8 possible values - no? I might be confusing the values that the vector can take and the value that the distribution parameters can take - but any help much appreciated

Comment: You may be confusing a random variable with a probability distribution.  A probability distribution over the set of $N$-vectors is given by $2^N$ probabilities, one for each possible vector.  Those probabilities must be non-negative and sum to unity.  Those are the only facts relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, a binary vector of length $N$ has $2^N$ possible states, so a probability distribution over all possible states requires specification of $2^N$ probabilities.  However, since the probabilities must sum to one, specification of any $2^N-1$ probabilities fully summarises the distribution.  Presumably this is what the authors mean when they refer to the "degrees-of-freedom" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

By degrees of freedom I guess it means the number of independent parameters required to completely define the probability distribution.
A general distribution we would need $2^N-1$ since all the variables are dependent.
But in a independent only knowing $N$ values we can get the all of the distribution.
Since it's just multiplying the values as they are independent.